# How to profile number of cycles stalled between two instructions in ARM Neon?

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

for example

```
    VMUL q0,q1,q2     
    VMUL q1,q0,q2

@VMUL needs 4 cycles for operation & result will be available by 7th cycle 
@next instruction will start only by 7th cycle so 5th, 6th cycle will stalled
@but next instruction need operate only by 2nd cycle of its beginning, 
@so it will start in 6th cycle itself. Result: 5th cycle is stalled 
@this is my understanding from manual.
```

1. is my consideration correct? if not please rectify.
2. Now i want to know how many cycles are stalled in between two instruction or in whole file. how to profile that?

Comment: would probably need to be something built into the chip for this purpose

Comment: Instruction cycle timings and latencies are heavily dependent on the micro-architecture. Which cpu are you actually talking about?

Comment: Your calculations don't take into account potential memory read latencies in instructions above the ones you cited. As @EOF says, cycle timing can change drastically between different CPU architectures. Some ARM CPUs have dual-issue out-of-order pipelines. Best way is to measure it on your target platform and try to avoid register contention in your code.

Comment: @BitBank measure in on your target.. that's my question. how to do?

Comment: @EOF cortex-a8.. i want to measure how many cycles it takes on my target. how to do?

Answer (score -1):

As the commenters have mentioned, this is a micro-architecture specific problem. Many implementations are proprietary and private, and tools, if even available, are extremely expensive. However, if you want to test very small math routines, and if the ARM-v7 ISA is your target, there is an online simulator for a basic "stock" A8:

http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/index.php?lng=us

This will help you get a feel for an older micro-architecture, and if it performs well for that, it will probably perform even better on newer micro-architectures.

I also feel that this tool is well designed and makes it easy to see the stalls and understand what's going on.

However, it is mostly for educational purposes. If you need to quote hard numbers, and be very specific for your manager or client, then I agree with the other comments that the only way to do it is with a full real-world benchmark on the platform you are targeting.

Comment: This site no longer exists

Comment: sad. it was really useful.  can't find it anywhere.